# Is it a bad practice to have multiple classes in the same file?

Tags: file, class, oop, language-agnostic

I used to have one class for one file. For example *car.cs* has the class *car*. But as I program more classes, I would like to add them to the same file. For example *car.cs* has the class *car* and the *door* class, etc.

My question is good for Java, C#, PHP or any other programming language. Should I try not having multiple classes in the same file or is it ok?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I think you should try to keep your code to 1 class per file.

I suggest this because it will be easier to find your class later. Also, it will work better with your source control system (if a file changes, then you know that a particular class has changed).

The only time I think it's correct to use more than one class per file is when you are using internal classes... but internal classes are inside another class, and thus can be left inside the same file. The inner classes roles are strongly related to the outer classes, so placing them in the same file is fine.

Comment: After seeing what kotlin can do in one file I start to believe that some things like DTOs could be in one file.

Comment: To add to this, the classes you'd have in the same file are typically closely related, which can make editing difficult because it's not as easy to view multiple classes simultaneously. You have to scroll around a lot. A split view helps, but it's not as easy as just having a separate window for each file/class.

Comment: What about autoloading?
When defining multiple classes in one source file the autoloading function will become more complex.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982012/php-is-autoloader-able-to-load-multiple-class-in-a-single-php-file

Answer (score 30):

In Java, one *public* class per file is the way the language works.   A group of Java files can be collected into a package.

In Python, however, files are "modules", and typically have a number of closely related classes.  A Python package is a directory, just like a Java package.

This gives Python an extra level of grouping between class and package.

There is no one right answer that is language-agnostic.  It varies with the language.

Answer (score 29):

One class per file is a good rule, but it's appropriate to make some exceptions.  For instance, if I'm working in a project where most classes have associated collection types, often I'll keep the class and its collection in the same file, e.g.:

```
public class Customer { /* whatever */ }

public class CustomerCollection : List<Customer> { /* whatever */ }
```

The best rule of thumb is to keep one class per file except when that starts to make things harder rather than easier.  Since Visual Studio's Find in Files is so effective, you probably won't have to spend much time looking through the file structure anyway.

Comment: No. This is bad advice. Take the advice of the accepted answer. You should separate the object repository from the class you saving. It simply creates unnecassary confusion.

Comment: @Hudson I don't see any "object repository" code above.

Comment: I agree with the thumb rule, but not in the provided scenario, because you're talking about 2 different data types. The best is to group them under the same folder structure in the provided sample.

Answer (score 27):

No I don't think it's an entirely bad practice. What I mean by that is in general it's best to have a separate file per class, but there are definitely good exception cases where it's better to have a bunch of classes in one file. A good example of this is a group of Exception classes, if you have a few dozen of these for a given group does it really make sense to have separate a separate file for each two liner class? I would argue not. In this case having a group of exceptions in one class is much less cumbersome and simple IMHO.

Answer (score 15):

Since your **IDE** Provides you with a "**Navigate to**" functionality  and you have some control over **namespacing** within your classes  then the below  benefits of having multiple classes within the same file are quite worth it for me.

**Parent - Child Classes**

In many cases i find it quite helpful to have **Inherited** classes within their **Base** Class file.

It's quite easy then to see which properties and methods your child class inherits  and the file provides a faster overview of the overall functionality.

**Public: Small - Helper - DTO  Classes**

When you need several **plain** and **small** classes for a **specific functionality** i find it quite redundant to have a file with all the references and includes for just a **4-8 Liner** class.....

**Code navigation** is also easier just scrolling over one file instead of switching between 10 files...Its also easier to **refactor** when you have to edit just  one reference instead of 10.....

Overall breaking the **Iron rule of 1 class per file** provides some extra **freedom** to organize your code.

What happens then, really depends on your IDE, Language,Team Communication and Organizing Skills.

But if you want that freedom why sacrifice it for an iron rule?

Answer (score 14):

I've found that whenever I try to combine multiple types into a single file, I always end going back and separating them simply because it makes them easier to find. Whenever I combine, there is always ultimately a moment where I'm trying to figure out wtf I defined type x.

So now, my personal rule is that each individual type (except maybe for child classes, by which a mean a class inside a class, not an inherited class) gets its own file.

Answer (score 11):

The rule I always go by is to have one *main* class in a file with the same name.  I may or may not include helper classes in that file depending on how tightly they're coupled with the file's main class.  Are the support classes standalone, or are they useful on their own?  For example, if a method in a class needs a special comparison for sorting some objects, it doesn't bother me a bit to bundle the comparison functor class into the same file as the method that uses it.  I wouldn't expect to use it elsewhere and it doesn't make sense for it to be on its own.

Answer (score 10):

If you are working on a team, keeping classes in separate files make it easier to control the source and reduces chances of conflicts (multiple developers changing the same file at the same time). I think it makes it easier to find the code you are looking for as well.

Answer (score 6):

It can be bad from the perspective of future development and maintainability.  It is much easier to remember where the Car class is if you have a Car.cs class.  Where would you look for the Widget class if Widget.cs does not exist?  Is it a car widget?  Is it an engine widget?  Oh maybe it's a bagel widget.

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360643/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-multiple-classes-in-the-same-file/360675#360675, with common navigation tools you do not have to navigate by file anyway. You navigate by classes / members instead.

Answer (score 6):

The **only** time I consider file locations is when I have to create new classes. Otherwise I *never* navigate by file structure. I Use "go to class" or "go to definition".

I know this is somewhat of a training issue; freeing yourself from the physical file structure of projects requires practice. It's very rewarding though ;)

If it feels good to put them in the same file, be my guest. Cant do that with public classes in java though  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should refrain from doing so, unless you have a good reason.

One file with several small related classes can be more readable than several files.
For example, when using 'case classes', to simulate union types, there is a strong relationship between each class.
Using the same file for multiple classes has the advantage of grouping them together visually for the reader.

In your case, a car and a door do not seem related at all, and finding the door class in the car.cs file would be unexpected, so don't.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, one class/one file is the way to go. I often keep several interface definitions in one file, though. Several classes in one file? Only if they are *very* closely related somehow, and very small (< 5 methods and members)

Answer (score 2):

As is true so much of the time in programming, it depends greatly on the situation.

For instance, what is the cohesiveness of the classes in question?  Are they tightly coupled?  Are they completely orthogonal?  Are they related in functionality?

It would not be out of line for a web framework to supply a general purpose widgets.whatever file containing BaseWidget, TextWidget, CharWidget, etc.

A user of the framework would not be out of line in defining a more_widgets file to contain the additional widgets they derive from the framework widgets for their specific domain space.

When the classes are orthogonal, and have nothing to do with each other, the grouping into a single file would indeed be artificial.  Assume an application to manage a robotic factory that builds cars.  A file called parts containing CarParts and RobotParts would be senseless... there is not likely to be much of a relation between the ordering of spare parts for maintenance and the parts that the factory manufactures.  Such a joining would add no information or knowledge about the system you are designing.

Perhaps the best rule of thumb is don't constrain your choices by a rule of thumb.  Rules of thumb are created for a first cut analysis, or to constrain the choices of those who are not capable of making good choices.  I think most programmers would like to believe they are capable of making good decisions.

Answer (score 2):

The Smalltalk answer is: you should not have files (for programming). They make versioning and navigation painful.

Answer (score 1):

One class per file is simpler to maintain and much more clear for anyone else looking at your code.  It is also mandatory, or very restricted in some languages.

In Java for instance, you cannot create multiple top level classes per file, they have to be in separate files where the classname and filename are the same.

Answer (score 0):

(C#) Another exception (to one file per class) I'm thinking of is having List in the same file as MyClass. Where I envisage using this is in reporting. Having an extra file just for the List seems a bit excessive.