# Multiple Class in one file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

Recently I was studying the possibility of creating multiple classes in only one file, for this I created a class of UIViewController with a .xib file, the structure of the file is as follows:

**MyFristViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyFristViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface MySecondViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**MyFristViewController.m**

```
@implementation MyFristViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Frist View Loaded");
}

@end


@implementation MySecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Second View Loaded");
}

@end
```

My doubt is: How does the system know that is to perform the methods contained in the class called **'MyFristViewController'**?

I already tried to modify the custom class in interface builder, tried to change the position of the classes in the file and the system continues running only the existing methods inside the **'MyFristViewController'** class why?

Comment: Why not? It is clearly demarcated which class is which. File names are completely irrelevant; they are just a convenience to _you_. It is not at all clear what you are surprised at.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the system know that is to perform the methods contained in the class called 'MyFristViewController'?

The filenames are irrelevant. When looking at a class, for the most part, the code between `@implementation <#ClassName#>` and `@end` is used.

Additional customization of classes can be added through [categories and class extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1). These can also be specified in the same file, or different files, because (again) the filenames are irrelevant.

Generally, you should have one class per file to make it easy to read and find your code. See [How many classes should a programmer put in one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469887/1445366) for additional discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is: How does the system know that is to perform the methods contained in the class called 'MyFristViewController'?

Because the methods are in the `@implementation` block of `MyFristViewController`.

> I already tried to modify the custom class in interface builder, tried to change the position of the classes in the file and the system continues running only the existing methods inside the 'MyFristViewController' class why?

Probably because you've linked them to the methods in first `@interface` section in your header file. Control-drag to the actual method you want to bind to. It's not clear what problem you're actually seeing.

That said, this is a terrible idea. Put each view controller in its own file. It'll work in one file, but it will create lots of confusion, as you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on projects that define multiple classes in a single file. I **loathe** this practice. I find it very disorienting and I waste a lot of time searching for where the classes are defined/implemented.

I would advise you not to do this. It ends up being very confusing.