# PHP: Is AutoLoader able to load multiple class in a single php file？

Tags: php, autoload

Quote from [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) :

> Many developers writing object-oriented applications create one PHP
>   source file per class definition. One of the biggest annoyances is
>   having to write a long list of needed includes at the beginning of
>   each script (one for each class).
>
> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. The spl_autoload_register()
>   function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and
>   interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not
>   defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to
>   load the class or interface before it fails with an error.

Here comes the question, what if there are multiple classes in a single php file, is it suitable for autoload usage? or do I have to use `require filepath` statement?

For example, I have a protocol file under Protobuf\Client.php:

```
<?php

namespace Protobuf;
class A {
...
}
class B {
...
}
```

Comment: You would have to have some complex function to autoload those classes from the file named `Client.php`. The idea is to translate your namespace\classname into a `directory\filename.php`

Comment: In this instance you would need to name your file `A.php` then when you call `new Protobuf\A()` it will find it. Otherwise you will have to create a overly-complex autoloader.

Comment: Finally, if you do create it so the autoloader finds the `A` class, then you can have `B` on the same file, but only if you have already autoloaded `A` otherwise  you have to make some algorythm to know that `A` and `B` are on the same page.

Comment: @Rasclatt, "copy paste" your three comments as an answer, you are correct.

Comment: @P0lT10n Yeah, I probably should. It was a rolling thought that I kept elaborating on...sort of got long winded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to have some complex function to autoload those classes from the file named `Client.php`. The idea is to translate your `namespace\classname` into a `directory\filename.php`

In this instance you would need to name your file `A.php` then when you call `new Protobuf\A()` it will find it. Otherwise you will have to create an overly-complex autoloader.

Let's say you do create the autoloader so it finds the `A` class, then you can have `B` on the same file, but only if you have already autoloaded `A` otherwise you have to make some algorythm to know that `A` and `B` are on the same page.

I would do the above pattern or the pattern adopted by apps like *Magento* that turn class names into directory paths by replacing underscores:

```
$class = new Core_Classes_MyClass_Client();
```

Your autoloader would replace the underscores and will load:

```
Core/Classes/MyClass/Client.php //or similar scheme
```

This to me is an easy way to do it, but I prefer using namespace and class. The above method is not in favor at the moment and from a naming standpoint, very easy to get mixed up since a lot of classes may be in the same folder or nested really deep into sub folders. You could get some really long naming for classes.

Comment: psr-0 namespacing ftw.

Comment: I can add to this answer, that the best approach is to have every class in a single file, so the autoloader (as described by author's answer) will find any class you are calling by the `namespace\classname` convention

Comment: I'm very glad to find such informative discussion. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question directly, we can use `classmap` for `autoload` in `composer.json` to support the single file containing multiple class.

For example we are going to support the single file `Protobuf\Client.php`, which has two class `A` and `B` in it:

```
<?php

namespace Protobuf;

class A {
}

class B {
}
```

We add `classmap` in the `composer.json` as following:

```
{
    "name": "hailong/myproj",
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "Protobuf/Client.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then, in `main.php` we can use class `A` and `B`:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Protobuf\A;
use Protobuf\B;

$a = new A();

$b = new B();
```

Finally, don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` after changing the `composer.json`, which will magically generate the `autoload.php` that required in our `main.php`.

For people not quit familiar with the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) yet, here is the final files structure we will get:

```
myproj % tree
.
├── Protobuf
│   └── Client.php
├── composer.json
├── main.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── autoload_static.php
        └── installed.json

3 directories, 12 files
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Rasclatts very informative answer,

Ideally, it's always good practice to separate classes when it comes to autoloading. I strongly recommend looking into composers PSR-0 Namespace Autoloading

PSR-0 Allows you to beautifully organise all your classes into sub folders with infinite depth, take the following folder structure

```
\system
 - Members
     - Members.php
 - Auth
     - Auth.php
 - Database
     - Database.php
```

For this example, in each of the php files above you would have `namespace MyNameSpace;` before your class declaration and then in your `composer.json` you would have something similar to ([documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0)):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "MyNameSpace": "/system" }
}
```

Composer should be installed on your local/host computer for you to compile your autoload files, open terminal and navigate to your project directory and type:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Now everything is neatly organised and you can access your classes similar to:

```
\MyNameSpace\Auth::staticFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes And NO,
But what if I do generate (automaticaly) classes and methods for a very large WSDL ?

ie. for a more than hundred methods You would have probably hundred methodRequests (as a class object), next hundred methodResponse (as a Class Object) and large arrays ie ClassMap.

Sometimes it's better to handle that stuff in one file, especialy when developing without good docs for WSDL.